# How can I let python print out the right output using a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I created a list and a function that returns a seperate list as a dictionary, like this
so the first list is this

```
r = ["T-bone", "Green Salad1"]
```

and the function that returns output as a dictionary is this...

```
def rdict(recipes):
    recipes_splitted = {}
    for r in recipes:
        recipe_name, parts = r.split(":")
        recipe_parts = {}
        for part in parts.split(','):
            product, number = part.split('*')
            recipe_parts[product] = int(number)
        recipes_splitted[recipe_name] = recipe_parts
    return recipes_splitted
```

The output from the function above is in a **dictionary** like this btw

```
{'Pork Stew': {'Cabbage': 5, 'Carrot': 1, 'Fatty Pork': 10}, 'Green Salad1': {'Cabbage': 10, 'Carrot': 2, 'Pineapple': 5}, 'T-Bone': {'Carrot': 2, 'Steak Meat': 1}}
```

So now, I'm trying to create a function `extract(recipes, data)` that will return the values from the dictionary provided and matching keys provided by the list. The return type shall be a list.

So for instance if the input is

```py
extract(recipes = ["T-bone", "Green Salad1"], data = {'Pork Stew': {'Cabbage': 5, 'Carrot': 1, 'Fatty Pork': 10}, 'Green Salad1': {'Cabbage': 10, 'Carrot': 2, 'Pineapple': 5}, 'T-Bone': {'Carrot': 2, 'Steak Meat': 1}}  )
```

The output would return the following list

```
["Carrot:2, Steak Meat:1","Cabbage: 10, Carrot: 2, Pineapple: 5"]
```

What should I write under estract(recipes, data) to get the correct output??

Comment: What do you expect the return type to be ? You cannot have the same key (`Carrot`) twice in a dict.

Comment: No carrot is not the key... carrot is part of T-bone and Green Salad in my example... I jus want a code that will return ["Carrot:2, Steak Meat:1","Cabbage: 10, Carrot: 2, Pineapple: 5"] when Tbone and Green Salad1 are called

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def extract(recipes, data):
    result = []
    for r in recipes:
        result.append(", ".join(f"{k}:{v}" for k, v in data[r].items()))
    return result
```

Result:

```py
['Carrot:2, Steak Meat:1', 'Cabbage:10, Carrot:2, Pineapple:5']
```

- Edit

Without `join`, `items`, and `dict` comprehension:

```py
def extract(recipes, data):
    result = []
    for r in recipes:
        tmp = []
        for key in data[r]:
            tmp.append(f"{key}:{data[r][key]}")
        final_string = ""
        for i in range(len(tmp)):
            if i < len(tmp) - 1:
                final_string += tmp[i] + ", "
            else:
                final_string += tmp[i]
        result.append(final_string)
    return result
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without using .items?? I would like to use as less built in functions as possible

Comment: Thank u for ur response btw

Comment: Why?
Also just recognized, that the above solution will compare keys precisely, so the example provided will not return `T-Bone` as your list asks for `T-bone`. If you want to make this work, you must provide a correct key or work with ignoring cases.

Comment: @JoshuaBradley I mean, sure, I can update the answer to give an example without `join` but it really makes things easier.

@Greenfly77 I also saw `T-Bone` and `T-bone` issue but thought it's just a typo.

Comment: Apparently there is a keyerror for T-Bone in this, is there smth wrong??

Comment: @JoshuaBradley In your data `dict` you have `T-Bone` but in `recipes` list you have `T-bone`. Just be sure that your `recipes` list contains exact keys as your data. That's all